# I'm not sure that my definition of indexed set product is valid.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I'm studying set theory, I saw the definition of indexed set product in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products).

The definition looks complicated to me, so I tried to define simpler. The definition is below.

$$\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}} X_i:=\left\{\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\left\{\left\{x_i,i\right\}\right\} \;\middle|\; x_i\in X_i\right\}$$

As I'm a beginner and have no colleague, I'm not sure. Is the definition correct?

Reference.
[Hausdorff's definition - wikipeida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Hausdorff.27s_definition)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if what you've written is correct or not, I don't think I understand it.. But needless to say, the product of sets is just all tuples of ordered elements from each set. If the product is 'too infinite' then you may have to characterize the product in terms of functions, but the idea is exactly the same. It's all possible 'elements' formed by choosing one 'element' from each set $X_i$.

Comment: Ah, I see now - you are using that Hausdorff convention. In that case, I guess your definition is correct. But note that, at least when dealing with infinite products, there is not really a notion of "order". That is why the wiki page uses functions, because they eliminate the need to explicitly enumerate all the elements in the set. But yes, it looks like you understand what the idea is.

Comment: Your definition is not okay. For instance in part $...\mid x_i\in X_i$ the $i$ seems to be some individual that is not ranging over any set.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Thank you sir. I perfectly understood your nice and clear answer.

Comment: @drhab $i$ denotes an element of $\mathcal{I}$, the index set.

Comment: I understand, but which element? If there is no answer to that since it is not a particular element of the indexset then it should *range* over the index set. This is not the case.

Comment: @drhab Why not? I don't understand why is this not the case.

Comment: Your definition has the form $\left\{ A\mid x_{i}\in X_{i}\right\} $.
If this is indeed a well-defined set, then what are its elements?

Comment: @drhab Should I add quantification on the conditional? (i.e. $i\in\mathcal{I}$.)

Comment: It goes too far to handle this by comments. I advice you just to drop your idea of 'simpler definition' and to accept what you found on Wikipedia. To promote that I have added an answer wich is not exactly an answer to your question, but more an explanation of the concept of products.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a set and let $X_{i}$ be a set for each $i\in I$.

What can serve as *product* for these sets is a *set* $X$ *together with functions*
(*projections*) $p_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ for $i\in I$ in
such a way that there is a one-to-one correspondence between so-called
'sources' of functions $\left\{ g_{i}:Y\rightarrow X_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$
and functions $g:Y\rightarrow X$. The fact that it is more convenient to handle with a *function* instead of a *source of functions* is an important motivation for constructing products.

For a source  $\left\{ g_{i}:Y\rightarrow X_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ a unique
function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ must exist such that $g_{i}=p_{i}\circ g$ for each $i\in I$ and conversely
every function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ induces source $\left\{ p_{i}\circ g:Y\rightarrow X_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$.

How to construct such a product?

In special case $I=\left\{ 1,2\right\} $
we can do with $X=\left\{ \left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\mid x_{1}\in X_{1},x_{2}\in X_{2}\right\} $
and projections $p_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ prescribed by $\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\mapsto x_{i}$
for $i=1,2$.

More generally we mostly choose for a set $X$ whose
elements are exactly the functions $f:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}X_{i}$
that satisfy the condition that $f\left(i\right)\in X_{i}$ for each
$i\in I$. Projections $p_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ are here the functions
prescribed by $f\mapsto f\left(i\right)$.

If we deal with a source
of functions $\left\{ g_{i}:Y\rightarrow X_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$
then for every $y\in Y$ there is a unique function $f_{y}:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}X_{i}$
that is determined by the condition $f_{y}\left(i\right)=g_{i}\left(y\right)\in X_i$
for $i\in I$. This $f_{y}$ is an element of $X$ which allows us to define $g:Y\rightarrow X$ by the prescription $y\mapsto f_{y}$.
We have: $$p_{i}\circ g\left(y\right)=p_{i}\left(g\left(y\right)\right)=p_{i}\left(f_{y}\right)=f_{y}\left(i\right)=g_{i}\left(y\right)$$
This for each $y\in Y$ and each $i\in I$, showing that indeed $p_{i}\circ g=g_{i}$
for each $i\in I$.

If we give a description of this set $X$ then we come to: $$X=\left\{ f\in\left(\cup_{i\in I}X_{i}\right)^{I}\mid\forall i\in I\; f\left(i\right)\in X_{i}\right\}$$ Here
$\left(\cup_{i\in I}X_{i}\right)^{I}$ is a notation for the set of
all functions $I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}X_{i}$.

Normally set  $X$ is denoted as $\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$. Essential (and often forgotten) is the fact that:

**a product is not just a set, but a set accompanied by projections**.

Comment: I don't see the benefit, in the case of set theory, of dragging the projections along when you can have a concrete set. I agree that in the case of a more general categorical settings it's true that you think about the product as some limit of a diagram or whatever, but in set theory? Why complicate things?

Comment: I will not dispute that. For me *personally* the 'complication' of projections worked more as some revelation and made things more clear to me. I hope on a sort-like effect for the OP, but admit that it can work out wrongly. Also I am more a 'categorist' than someone who knows about set-theory.

Comment: I could have guessed that last sentence from the given answer, you know. :-) I bet you think that a function is an ordered triplet, and not just a set of ordered pairs with a certain property! ;-)

Comment: Indeed. Before I answer questions on that subject I must always have a look at the tags of the question at first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more complicated to me. Your unions are precisely the functions $\mathcal I\to\bigcup X_i$, just written in a less intuitive way. When you write $\{x_i\}_{\mathcal I} $, that's nothing but a function,  which you would see more clearly if you wrote $x(i) $ instead of $x_i$ (I'm not suggesting you actually do it, but it might help you see it).

Comment: Nice answer, sir. But I rather use my definition cause it is ironic that usually, to define _function_, the notion of cartesian product is critical. So in the manner of formalizing procedure, we have to define _cartesian product_ first. Honestly, I don't like the definition from wiki.